# Can you use css term "@media" in html style=""

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in which i need to use @media in html. You use @media in css but now i need to use it in html but i cannot find a way on how to do so.

I expect to change some styling

Comment: No, you can't inline `@media`.

Comment: use it in a `<style>` tag

Comment: can't use "id or class" therefore style won't work

Comment: There are many selectors other than ID and class selectors. They can be combined in many ways. (And if you can change the HTML to add a style attribute then you should be able to add other data too).

Comment: No, you can't. Just use a `<style>` tag and do it in there. I'm not sure why you would want to do it inline, or can't use id/class. Maybe use a `data-*` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The value of a `style` attribute is equivalent to the body of a rule-set.

Rule-sets can go inside media queries. The reverse is not true.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add tag style and write inside it your @media css code, for example

```
<div>Element</div>
<style>
@media (max-width:360px){
    div{
      display: none;
    }
}
</style>
```